# How to retrieve if Twitter deemed a Tweet harmful?

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python

So I am creating a small telegram-twitter bot for friends and me. So far everything works, I get the tweets and forward them to the telegram chat. All cool. But then I figured that it would be cool to display if Twitter deemed the Tweet to be incorrect or harmful. Does anybody know how retrieve or access this information without scraping the webpage?

I checked the API and even the [labs api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/tweets-and-users/api-reference/get-tweets-id), but couldn't find anything.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the Twitter API that provides this information.

Comment: damn, I expected as much. is there a non-TOS-violating way to get this information?